# Redirecting tar stdout and eerout to log file with piped openssl encryption

Tags: bash, redirect, pipe, outputstream

I've a script that takes an encrypted tar and pushes to s3 bucket. I am not able to redirect the output and errors to log files.

It works without using a pipe with another command:

```
tar -zcvf logs.tgz logs > logs.log 2> logs_errors.log
```

When I pipe it with openssl encryption, every thing works but stdout and error are still not redirected to the log files and only displayed on screen.

```
tar zcvf - logs | openssl enc -e -aes256 -pass "pass:secretpass" -out test123.tgz.enc  > test123.log 2> test123_error.log
```

I need to redirect stdout and errors to their respective files.

Thanks in advance.

When I pipe it with openssl encryption, every thing works but stdout and error are still not redirected to the log files and only displayed on screen.

Comment: `# Create encrypted backup archive

(tar zcvf - $backup_src_tpfs_files | openssl enc -e -aes256 -pass "pass:$enc_key" \
-out ${backup_dest}/${server_name}_tpfs_backup_${backup_date}.tgz.enc ) 2> ${backup_dest}/${server_name}_tpfs_backup_${backup_date}.log &
(tar zcvf - $backup_src_html_files | openssl enc -e -aes256 -pass "pass:$enc_key" \
-out ${backup_dest}/${server_name}_html_backup_${backup_date}.tgz.enc ) 2> ${backup_dest}/${server_name}_html_backup_${backup_date}.log &

wait
`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using parentheses to group the commands together and then redirect the output and error streams of the entire group like this :

```
(tar zcvf - logs | openssl enc -e -aes256 -pass "pass:secretpass" -out test123.tgz.enc) > test123.log 2> test123_error.log
```

Comment: Tried that, now decryption errors out with the below error:


gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child died with signal 13
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
error writing output file

Comment: Hmm.. `tar` is not being properly piped into `openssl`.

Comment: How about `tar zcvf - logs | openssl enc -e -aes256 -pass "pass:secretpass" | tee test123.tgz.enc | gzip > /dev/null 2> test123_error.log > test123.log`? Use `tee`